# How to buy videos, ebooks, music at ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, multimedia, media

What's the solution for that? The Amazon Kindle Reader is only for Windows and Mac, für Linux there's only a MP3 downloader from amazon, but only for older systems and 32-Bit.

Is there something similar to iTunes for ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Amazon Kindle Cloud Reader](https://read.amazon.com/) it is possible to read your Kindle ebooks with Chromium or Firefox. On my opinion this is a good replacement for the native Kindle app on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There is the Ubuntu One music store, which is included by default on Ubuntu, and is accessible from the Rhythmbox player, from the Music Lens in the Dash, and from the Ubuntu One website.

Amazon no longer supports Linux exactly, particularly if you live in the US.

Comment: So there are several good possibilities for music, but, what about ebooks?

Comment: And, how do I buy music from amazon using banshee?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about e-books and video's but `clamz` (installed by running `sudo apt-get install clamz`) is able to download mp3 files from amazon music by reading the `.amz` files and works on all versions of ubuntu. Instructions for setup and use can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/clamz/).

As for itunes like programs there is Rhythmbox, which is installed by default, along with Banshee, Clementine, Amarock and all sorts of others which can be found in the software center.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu12.10 onwards, a new shopping lens has been added to Unity.You can read more about it on [OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/online-shopping-features-arrive-in-ubuntu-12-10) . This lens include all the relevant results from Amazon.